# IoT Edge: SimulatedTemperatureSensor not working on my Raspberry 3 A+

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 A+ and I downloaded Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit to my hardware. I have installed IoT edge in accordance to these instructions: [Create and provision an IoT Edge device on Linux using symmetric keys.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-symmetric?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=azure-portal%2Cubuntu) Connecting to the IoT Hub and running the IoT Agent and IoT edge module works fine. The problem arises when I try to push an additional module.

I tried following these [Tutorial: Develop IoT Edge modules with Linux containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-linux?view=iotedge-1.4) to deploy an IoT Edge module. It works fine when I deploy it to a VM (Linux ubuntu 20.04 x64). But it does not work when I try do the same deployment to my Raspberry.

If you are not familiar with the instructions; This is the template code that gets created when you make a **Azure IoT Edge: New IoT Edge Solution* in VS Code. The only thing I have added is basically the name "temperatureTest". The rest of the code is generated for me. And as I mentioned, it works fine for the (Linux ubuntu 20.04 x64) VM. But it does not work when I push it to my Raspberry. (I do swap to the "Set Default Target Platform for Edge Solution" to arm32v7 before deploy my config file).

```
{
  "$schema-template": "4.0.0",
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.1",
        "runtime": {
          "type": "docker",
          "settings": {
            "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
            "loggingOptions": "",
            "registryCredentials": {
              "****": {
                "username": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME_****",
                "password": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD_****",
                "address": "****.azurecr.io"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "systemModules": {
          "edgeAgent": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.4",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
          },
          "edgeHub": {
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.4",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "PortBindings": {
                    "5671/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "5671"
                      }
                    ],
                    "8883/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "8883"
                      }
                    ],
                    "443/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "443"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "modules": {
          "temperatureTest": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.temperatureTest}",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
          },
          "SimulatedTemperatureSensor": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor:1.4",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.1",
        "routes": {
          "temperatureTestToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/temperatureTest/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
          "sensorTotemperatureTest": "FROM /messages/modules/SimulatedTemperatureSensor/outputs/temperatureOutput INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/temperatureTest/inputs/input1\")"
        },
        "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
          "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running the command *iotedge logs temperatureTest* on my raspberry gives the following output:

```
IoT Hub Client for Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/adapters.py",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              line 41, in connect
    sock.connect(socket_path)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 499,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in send
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              788, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 76                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             9, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/adapters.py",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              line 41, in connect
    sock.connect(socket_path)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             (111, 'Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 79, in <module>
    main()
  File "./main.py", line 55, in main
    client = create_client()
  File "./main.py", line 17, in create_client
    client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/aio/patch_docume                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ntation.py", line 224, in create_from_edge_environment
    return super(IoTHubModuleClient_, cls).create_from_edge_environment(**kwargs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/abstract_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             clients.py", line 688, in create_from_edge_environment
    server_verification_cert = hsm.get_certificate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/edge_hsm.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             py", line 65, in get_certificate
    headers={"User-Agent": urllib.parse.quote_plus(user_agent.get_iothub_user_ag                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ent())},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              line 51, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              line 46, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 547,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedEr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ror(111, 'Connection refused'))
IoT Hub Client for Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/adapters.py",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              line 41, in connect
    sock.connect(socket_path)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 499,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in send
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              788, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 76                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             9, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packaib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/adapters.py",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              line 41, in connect
    sock.connect(socket_path)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             (111, 'Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 79, in <module>
    main()
  File "./main.py", line 55, in main
    client = create_client()
  File "./main.py", line 17, in create_client
    client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/aio/patch_docume                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ntation.py", line 224, in create_from_edge_environment
    return super(IoTHubModuleClient_, cls).create_from_edge_environment(**kwargs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/abstract_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             clients.py", line 688, in create_from_edge_environment
    server_verification_cert = hsm.get_certificate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/edge_hsm.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             py", line 65, in get_certificate
    headers={"User-Agent": urllib.parse.quote_plus(user_agent.get_iothub_user_ag                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ent())},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              line 51, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              line 46, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 547,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedEr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ror(111, 'Connection refused'))
IoT Hub Client for Python
Subscribe for input failed.  Not enabling feature
./main.py:36: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'execute_patch_for_async.<locals>.shutdo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             wn' was never awaited
  client.shutdown()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/common/mqtt_tran                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             sport.py", line 396, in connect
    host=self._hostname, port=8883, keepalive=self._keep_alive
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 914, i                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             n connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1044,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3685,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, timeout=self._connect_timeout, source_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             address=source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 728, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/aio/async                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             _clients.py", line 33, in handle_result
    return await callback.completion()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/common/async_ada                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             pter.py", line 94, in completion
    return await self.future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/iot/device/common/pipeline/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             pipeline_stages_mqtt.py", line 193, in _run_op
    self.transport.connect(password=password)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to deploy the out of box [TemperatureSensor](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/azure-iot.simulated-temperature-sensor?tab=overview) [module provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux?view=iotedge-1.4#deploy-a-module) ? Looks like some configuration issue on your RaspberryPI

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it worked fine.  

What I eventually did was to reinstall Raspberry Pi OS 32 but this time I configured everything I needed with the Raspberry Imager (Wifi Password, hostname etc). I no longer followed these steps which were recommended by the tutorial
https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/raspberrypi-setup/. Im not sure what caused the problem but now it works at least.

Comment: Yes, I really like that blog as i personally learned from that so many initial steps to configure Raspberry Pi. Thanks for confirming that the issue is unblocked. I have posted few initial troubleshooting steps as an Answer, which i thought might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

So there are few things we have to investigate as we will not be able to troubleshoot the entire issue offline..

First, we have to make sure to update our IoT Device Firmware!

Update the firmware of your Raspberry Pi: `sudo rpi-update`

1. Try to deploy the out-of-the-box [TemperatureSensor](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/azure-iot.simulated-temperature-sensor?tab=overview) module [provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux?view=iotedge-1.4#deploy-a-module) , it may be some configuration issue on your RaspberryPI , this sample module deployment will make sure that there is no errors in the module code and the connection issues.
2. Check the version of the [operating system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/support?view=iotedge-1.4#operating-systems): `cat /etc/os-release`
   Check the version of .NET Core: `dotnet --version`
   Check the version of Docker: `docker --version`
3. Ping a website to verify internet connectivity: `ping www.google.com`
   Use traceroute to diagnose network issues: `traceroute www.google.com`
   This will help in verifying the connectivity.
4. Check the [Azure IoT Edge runtime logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot?view=iotedge-1.4#run-the-check-command): `sudo iotedge logs`
   Check the logs for a specific module: `sudo iotedge logs <module-name>`
   Always do this to get initial logs for troubleshooting!
5. This is my favorite step!
   Check the status of all modules: `sudo iotedge list`
   Check the status of a specific module: `sudo iotedge list <module-name>`
6. Restart the Azure IoT Edge runtime: `sudo systemctl restart iotedge`
   Restart a specific module: `sudo iotedge restart <module-name>`

** In some scenarios, I have seen that re-imaging the Raspberry pi with the right image may help in fixing so-many issues which are hidden and can't be traced via regular troubleshooting steps and docs.